# How to only generate code in debug release in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am new to Maven and I can't find how to generate `debug` and `release` optimized builds, as we have in other languages. Furthermore, I can't find how to make some parts of the code only available in a `debug` build as C# and other languages have the `#ifdef DEBUG`.

How can I make this work in Maven?

Comment: You should learn Java first...cause usually there no difference between them.  And conditionals compiling does not exist in Java and will never be...

Comment: Well, this won't sound any good, but I am an experienced Java programmer for the past 4 years lol... problem is, I mostly developed for android, so right now I am dealing more with AWS Lambda functions and Maven which is a paradigm shift and a new learning curve

Comment: Ok...You can in theory create debugging information during compilation if you like (`javac -g`, `javac -g:lines`  etc.) ..but to be honest never seen someone using it...only in extreme rare cases. And using -g option is not needed to debug code with IDE's.. You can if you like create profiles for a debugging version (changing the javac options?)...and use `javac -g:none` in other cases is of course possible..

Comment: See also https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#debuglevel

Comment: Well in android there's the release and debug builds in gradle, so I was thinking on something similar, but if for Maven there's no difference, then it's fine. It's the first time I needed conditional compiling because I don't want to export some code I only added for helping with testing.

Comment: @khmarbaise since you are so much more experienced in Maven than I am, could you take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808872/how-to-configure-maven-to-export-depenencies-in-lib-folder/53815585#53815585 the answer I got there doesn't work

Comment: If you have code which is only for testing you simply put that code into `src/test/java` and will automatically not packaged and distributed that's it...

Comment: I know, I have it there, it's just a main method that's useless for AWS Lambda, but I placed a full example there so I could trigger it from the console if I wanted to... But I already removed it anyway....

Comment: Right now I am just wondering how to follow the packaging recommendation from AWS, as in the link I sent before

Answer (score 0):

Maven has [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) that allow you to tweak your build process (e.g. by overriding plugin settings). These can be either explicitly selected when launching a Maven build or automatically activated based on environment settings.

I don't know of any really successful pre-processors for Java to recommend. In most cases besides assertions, runtime checks tend to be the number one substitute for #ifdefs.

My personal weapon of choice for handling debug/release-optimized features in compile-time is a combination of annotation processing ([quick intro here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder)) and aspect-oriented programming ([Spring AOP intro](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api)).